# Null prototype, Object.prototype and Object.create

Tags: javascript, prototype

Why is it that setting the prototype property of a constructor function to `null` does not prevent objects created from that function from calling through to methods on `Object.prototype`, in the same way that setting the prototype to `Object.create(null)` does?

That is, why is this the case:

```
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = null;
console.log(new Foo().toString); //outputs function toString() { [native code] } (or whatever)

function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = Object.create(null);
console.log(new Foo().toString); //output undefined
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### In short

**Yes**, your observation is correct - a function constructed with the `new` operator will *always* have an object prototype in this case `Object.prototype` and this is indeed unlike a function created with Object.create.

---

### On why

One can see this behavior completely specified in the ES5 language specification on which JavaScript is based on. Let's see this.

#### In `new`:

[Quoting the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2) of the `[[Construct]]` method of functions that indicates how object creation using the `new` operator is performed we can see that the following is specified:

> If Type(proto) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to the standard built-in Object prototype object as described in 15.2.4.

#### In `Object.create`:

On the other hand, if we check out [The spec for `Object.create`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.5) we can see that `Object.create(o)` specifies:

> Set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to O.

Which means we can set it, it also explicitly checks that it is null or Object in that algorithm (please *do* follow the link to the spec and read it :))

So the prototype of the objects called with `new Foo` is `Object.prototype` and not `null`. It is impossible to create objects with no prototype without `Object.create` using standard methods only.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it clearly explains the situation. I'll read the spec more often :P

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum guru!

Comment: @Bejamin Gruenbaum You wrote: "It is impossible to create objects with no prototype without Object.create using standard methods only." but you can do:  function Foo() {} and then Foo.prototype = { __proto__: null }, and then new Foo() will be an object with no prototype, the same as Object.create(null). What did I miss here ?

Comment: @EvaCohen You can also do `{ __proto__: null }` though that's not a mandatory part of JavaScript yet (they were talking about moving `__proto__` from the annex to the spec and certain environment like Deno don't implement it)

Comment: @EvaCohen In any case - this answer predates `__proto__` being a part of JavaScript (even in the annex) by several years.