# Create javascript object with null prototype without using Object.create

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I need to find a way to create a JavaScript object with `null` prototype.

I'm not allowed to use the `Object.create` function.

I tried instantiating a constructor like `new Constructor()`, but the returned object always has a non-`null` prototype, even if `Constructor.prototype === null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Null prototype, Object.prototype and Object.create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198178/null-prototype-object-prototype-and-object-create)

Answer (score 3):

Such an object already exists, it's `Object.prototype`, so your code is as simple as

```
x = Object.prototype
```

but you cannot create a new object like this, because `new` always sets the proto to an object:

> If Type(proto) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to the standard built-in Object prototype object as described in 15.2.4. @ http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2

You can manipulate `__proto__` directly

```
a = {}
a.__proto__ = null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {};
a.prototype = null;
alert(a.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to create an object that inherits from another without `Object.create` is instantiating a function with the desired `prototype`. However, as you say it won't work with `null`:

```js
function Null() {}
Null.prototype = null;
var object = new Null();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === null); // false :(
```

But luckily, ECMAScript 6 introduces classes. The approach above won't directly work neither because the `prototype` property of an ES6 class is non-configurable and non-writable.

However, you can take advantage of the fact that ES6 classes can extend `null`. Then, instead of instantiating, just get the `prototype` of the class:

```js
var object = (class extends null {}).prototype;
delete object.constructor;
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(object) === null); // true :)
```