# Explanation on why the empty object instance behave differently using Object.create

Tags: javascript

I ran the following in node.js v0.10.22.
I understand this initial object creation snippet:

```
> var o1 = {};
> var o2 = Object.create(null)
> var o3 = Object.create(Object.prototype);
> var o4 = Object.create({})

> o1
{}
> o2
{}
> o3
{}
> o4
{}

> o1.prototype === void 0
true
> o2.prototype === void 0
true
> o3.prototype === void 0
true
> o4.prototype === void 0
true
```

However the following confuses me:

```
> o1 instanceof Object
true
> o2 instanceof Object
false
> o3 instanceof Object
true
> o4 instanceof Object
true
```

What is the explanation behind this behaviour ?

Comment: Keep in mind that object instances do not have a property `prototype` to access their prototype - only their constructor function would have such a property. In Chrome, for example, you can access the prototype of an object instance via `o1.__proto__`

Comment: I get `true` for `o4 instanceof Object` when I run your code (node v0.10.13 as well as in Chrome browser console).

Comment: @TedHopp You are correct. I reran it & will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write something like that:

```
var ob = {}; 
// its equivalent to Object.create(Object.prototype)
```

When you write:

```
Object.create(null) 
// doesn't inherit from anywhere and thus has no properties at all.
```

In other words. a javascript object inherits from Object by default, unless you explicitly create it specifying null as its prototype, as in Object.create(null)

Also you must read this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198178/null-prototype-object-prototype-and-object-create), i think its great

Comment: great explanation.  Another great resource IMO is http://www.objectplayground.com/

Comment: @HelloWorld Thanks for you, objectplayground nice resource to learn))